# Snake body appears as a straight line

Tags: java, swing, animation, graphics

I am making a snake game; snake moves behind the cursor. The snake movement is working perfectly but its body appears as a line of circle.

Where as the circles are supposed to appear in there own boxes.I debugged the program and tried to figure out the problem, but after getting the values of x positions and y positions of every circle i m confused because it shows a gap of 20 pixels(size of circle) in btw every circle, so it should show them in their own boxes but its not. I can't figure out where is the problem, and this is my code of class which draws snake and moves it:

```
`import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel implements MouseMotionListener {
    int x_Cur;
    int y_Cur;
    int dots;
    int delta_x, delta_y;
    double angle;
    double x_inc, y_inc;
    double speed = 5.0;
    int max_points = (600 * 600);
    final int x_positions[] = new int[max_points];
    final int y_positions[] = new int[max_points];

    public Game() {
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setVisible(true);
        first_Snake();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            if (z == 0) {
                g.setColor(Color.yellow);
                g.fillOval(x_positions[z], y_positions[z], 20, 20);
            } else {
                g.setColor(Color.green);
                g.fillOval(x_positions[z], y_positions[z], 20, 20);
            }
            System.out.println("xs"+z+"="+x_positions[z]+"\n"+"ys"+z+"="+y_positions[z]);
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        delta_x = x_Cur - x_positions[0];
        delta_y = y_Cur - y_positions[0];
        angle = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        double speed = Math.sqrt(delta_x * delta_x + delta_y * delta_y);
        speed = Math.min(speed, 2.5);
        x_inc = (speed * Math.cos(angle));
        y_inc = (speed * Math.sin(angle));
        move();
    }
    public void move(){
        if(!(delta_x==0&&delta_y==0)){
            for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
                x_positions[z] = x_positions[z-1];
                y_positions[z] = y_positions[z-1];  
            } 
    }
        x_positions[0]+= x_inc;
        y_positions[0]+= y_inc;
            action();

    }
    public void action(){
        repaint();
    }

    public void first_Snake() {

        dots = 20;
        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            x_positions[z] = 50 - z * 20;
            y_positions[z] = 50;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {

        x_Cur = me.getX() - 20;
        y_Cur = me.getY() - 20;

    }
}`
```

and this is the class which contains the main method:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Snake extends JFrame {

    public Snake() {
        add(new Game());
         setTitle("Snake");
            pack();
            setResizable(false);
            setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {                
                    JFrame ex = new Snake();

                    ex.setVisible(true);                
                }
            });
        }
}
```

please help.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand without a screenshot or two. What does your app look like now, and what do you want it to look like?

Comment: Its not letting me to add images :(

Comment: Some thing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919493/snake-body-parts-not-positioning-properly) problem but its in C# so i cant understand it :(

Comment: Link your images from an external site, someone will edit them in for you.